# Error storing oauth credentials in session when authenticating with Google+

Tags: python, oauth, flask, google-oauth

I'm following a tutorial to authenticate using G+.  I have the following route to handle the authentication and put the credentials into the Flask session.  (The actual code is much longer, with error checks along the way.  It can be found in [my GitHub project](https://github.com/rubendarioramirez/catalog).)

Accessing the route gives an error about serialization.  I understand it's trying to serialize something that it can't.  How do I find that and fix that?

```
@app.route('/gconnect', methods=['POST'])
def gconnect():
    oauth_flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', scope='')
    oauth_flow.redirect_uri = 'postmessage'
    credentials = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(request.data)
    login_session['credentials'] = credentials
    login_session['gplus_id'] = credentials.id_token['sub']

    answer = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo', params={'access_token': credentials.access_token, 'alt': 'json'})
    data = answer.json()
    login_session['username'] = data['name']
    login_session['picture'] = data['picture']
    login_session['email'] = data['email']

    return make_response(json.dumps('Successfully connected user.', 200))
```

```
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Apr/2015 14:48:18] "POST /gconnect?state=Y8LV4CFTO00K16G09SLIZZ2CSGR3ZH32 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1479, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1693, in process_response
    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 837, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 326, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 537, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 809, in dump_payload
    json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 522, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 85, in dumps
    return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/json.py", line 126, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 369, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 262, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 340, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/json.py", line 83, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 239, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials object at 0xb57e388c> is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to store the credentials *object*, rather than the actual credential *data*, in the session.  The session data is serialized with JSON, so all data in it must be JSON serializable.

For a hint at what you actually need to store in the session to use the authentication you just performed, you can look at your request to `/userinfo`, where you send `credentials.access_token`.

The access token is typically what you need to remember after any oauth cycle.  Don't store the credentials object, just store the access token.

```
# remove the session['credentials'] line
login_session['access_token'] = credentials.access_token
```

Now you can use this token from the session in other routes to make other api calls.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and was able to convert the credentials object to json via

```
login_session['credentials'] = credentials.to_json()
```

Comment: After converting to JSON format how to get its original format from the JSON?